# Can't initialize recyclerView in android (kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, initialization, swipe

I have this problem where TaskAdapter is not initialized correctly and I don't know how to do it. This line of code is problem, when I uncomment it app doesn't work at all (crashes after splash screen). When it's commented, app works fine but without recyclerView at all. Can you see the code and write where to put and how to initialize recyclerView? Logcat picture is here below. I'm using Task class for every task and user generate it and saves to firebase. All tasks are represented in recyclerView in home fragment. You can delete every task with swipe gesture.

[Logcat error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIB5m.png)

UPDATED!!!!

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentHomeBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    private lateinit var taskRecyclerview: RecyclerView

    private var taskArrayList = mutableListOf<Task>()
    private val taskAdapter = TaskAdapter(taskArrayList)


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        taskRecyclerview = binding.taskList
        taskRecyclerview.adapter = taskAdapter

        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val swipeGestureTask = object : SwipeGesture() {
            override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
                val position: Int = viewHolder.adapterPosition
                taskArrayList.removeAt(position)
                taskRecyclerview.adapter?.notifyItemRemoved(position)

                val task = viewHolder.itemView.tag as Task
                val currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
                val uid = currentUser!!.uid
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(uid).child("Tasks")
                    .child(task.taskId!!).removeValue()
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Task successfully deleted !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }

        var itemTouchHelper = ItemTouchHelper(swipeGestureTask)
        itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(taskRecyclerview)
        taskRecyclerview.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false)
        taskRecyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true)
        taskArrayList = arrayListOf()
        getTaskData()



    private fun getTaskData() {
        val currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
        val uid = currentUser!!.uid
        val tasksPath =
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(uid).child("Tasks")
        tasksPath.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                taskArrayList.clear()
                for (taskSnapshot in snapshot.children) {
                    val task = taskSnapshot.getValue(Task::class.java)
                    taskArrayList.add(task!!)
                }
                taskAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                println("DATABASE ERROR.")
            }
        })
    }
}








class TaskAdapter(private val tasksList: List<Task>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<TaskAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {

        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
            R.layout.task_card,
            parent, false
        )
        return MyViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = tasksList[position]

        holder.itemView.tag = currentItem
        holder.taskName.text = currentItem.taskName
        holder.taskDesc.text = currentItem.taskDesc
        holder.taskCategory.text = currentItem.taskCategory
        holder.taskPriority.text = currentItem.taskPriority
        holder.taskTime.text = currentItem.taskTime + " min"
        holder.taskIsDone.isChecked = currentItem.taskIsDone ?: false

        holder.taskIsDone.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
            val currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
            val uid = currentUser!!.uid
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(uid).child("Tasks").child(currentItem.taskId!!).child("taskIsDone").setValue(isChecked)
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return tasksList.size
    }

    inner class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val taskName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.taskName)
        val taskDesc: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.taskDesc)
        val taskCategory: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.taskCategory)
        val taskPriority: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.taskPriority)
        val taskTime: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.taskTime)
        val taskIsDone: CheckBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.taskIsDone)

    }

}







data class Task(
    val taskId: String? = null,
    var taskName: String ?= null,
    val taskDesc: String ?= null,
    val taskCategory: String ?= null,
    val taskPriority: String ?= null,
    val taskTime: String ?= null,
    val taskIsDone: Boolean ?= false
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just move your line

```
taskRecyclerview = binding.taskList
```

in onCreateView, after the _binding initialization and it will work just fine.

Comment: I moved it and app is stable (not crashing anymore) but tasks are not presented in recyclerView. In Logcat i got message: E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Comment: you also have to add taskRecyclerview.adapter  = taskAdapter
right after where you put the first line

Comment: I done it and it says: E/ion: ioctl c0044901 failed with code -1: Invalid argument

App is stable (no crashes) but there aren't any tasks represented in recyclerView